# Automation test plan is not running with every release

Tags: c#, selenium, azure-devops, automated-tests, nunit

I have two test plan in azure devops server. When I run the new release then one test plan run. But if some test cases are failed on that test plan after that second test plan does not run. Looking forward to get a solution for this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: According to your description, please check if you are referring to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=azure-devops-2020#run-the-automated-tests

Comment: I mean, I have two test plan on server. When developer build a code and run the new release, then for that release my test plan should run. For now one of my test plan is running but if some test cases does not pass on that test plan then second test plan is not running. So I want some solution regarding this if this is possible.